# Configuring physical memory for linux kernel

Tags: linux, mips, u-boot, memory-size

I have an embedded board (MIPS architecture) running linux 2.6.29 with u-boot as the bootloader. I have 512MB(bytes) of DDR3 RAM.

The problem is, Linux is able to use only around 128MB of it. I tried changing the memory size while kernel compilation, but the kernel crashes while booting up.

Can somebody please help me with this?. I even tried passing `mem=512MB` as kernel command line parameter from uboot, but that didn't work.

Comment: I think this is better suited to go to superuser.

Comment: Debatable IMO, see my answer.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Torp - I think the OP may be hitting a caveat specific to MIPS, which isn't likely to be helped on SU. Fayaz, as this isn't really a programming question, it's probably a perfect fit for unix.stackexchange.com. I can close it here, or migrate it there .. which would you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

No experience with MIPS boards but a problem i've encountered on ARM is that the physical memory isn't mapped to 512 M of contiguous address space but split. Look at the memmap parameter for the kernel, and at the documentation for your board.